# How this integral $ \int_0^z\frac{1-e^x}{x} dx$ is connected to the Gamma function and Euler constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, special-functions

This is my first question in this forum; I hope it is an appropriate question.
The Wolframalpha website tells me that
$$
\int\nolimits_0^z\frac{1-e^x}{x} dx = \log (-z)+\Gamma(0, -z)+\gamma\quad \text{for}\quad \Re(z)<0.
$$
I tried to prove this for myself, but I would appreciate it if you could give 
me some help.
This is not a homework question, and I would appreciate it if someone could point me to a reference or tell me what you expect to happen when $ℜ(z)>0$.
Thanks.

Comment: I know what $\Gamma(z)$ means, but what does $\Gamma(0,z)$ mean?

Comment: @Srivatsan, [incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) (the "special values" section connects $\Gamma(0,z)$ to the exponential integral; don't know why Wolfram favors the former).

Comment: @Henning: The incomplete gamma and exponential integral functions are essentially equivalent, anyway. I presume the use incomplete gamma since the internal algorithms for integration start out with hypergeometrics and specialize accordingly, incomplete gamma being one of the more convenient special cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that this works for both positive and negative $z$.

By definition and  change of variables
$$
\Gamma(0,-z)=\int_{-z}^\infty e^{-x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=-\int_{-\infty}^z e^x\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\tag{1}
$$
where the principal value is taken where needed. Applying $(1)$ to the integral from $w$ to $z$:
$$
\int_w^z\frac{1-e^x}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\log|z|-\log|w|+\Gamma(0,-z)-\Gamma(0,-w)\tag{2}
$$
According to $(2)$,
$$
\int_0^z\frac{1-e^x}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\log|z|+\Gamma(0,-z)-C\tag{3}
$$
where
$$
C=\lim_{w\to0}(\log|w|+\Gamma(0,|w|))\tag{4}
$$
We can use $\Gamma(0,|w|)$ in $(4)$ since either $\Gamma(0,w)$ or $\Gamma(0,-w)$ is defined by a principal value integral, so we have
$$
\lim_{w\to0}(\Gamma(0,-w)-\Gamma(0,w))=0
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
C
&=\lim_{w\to0}(\log|w|+\Gamma(0,|w|))\\
&=\lim_{w\to0}\left(\log|w|+\int_{|w|}^\infty e^{-x}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\right)\\
&=\lim_{w\to0}\left(\log|w|-\log|w|\;e^{-|w|}+\int_{|w|}^\infty\log(x)e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\int_0^\infty\log(x)e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\gamma\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). Combining $(3)$ and $(6)$, we get
$$
\int_0^z\frac{1-e^x}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\log|z|+\Gamma(0,-z)+\gamma\tag{7}
$$
If there is interest, I can append a proof that $\int_0^\infty\log(x)e^{-x}\mathrm{d}x=-\gamma$.

Comment: Thank Robjonh, beautiful explanation!

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you misquote WolframAlpha. It give $\int_0^z \left( 1- \mathrm{e}^x \right) \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{x} = \gamma + \log(-z) + \Gamma(0, -z)$. Notice $\Gamma(0, -z)$ instead of $\Gamma(0, z)$.

This is done using the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus):

Let
$$
 F(x) = \int \left( 1- \mathrm{e}^x \right) \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{x} = \log(x) - \operatorname{Ei}(x) 
$$
Then, $\int_0^z \left( 1- \mathrm{e}^x \right) \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{x} = F(z) - \lim_{x\to 0^+} F(x) = F(z) + \gamma$. The latter limit follows from the Taylor series for the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

The connection between $\Gamma(0,-z) = \int_{-z}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x} \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{x}$ and $\operatorname{Ei}(z) = \int_{-\infty}^z \mathrm{e}^{x} \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{x}$ is well known.

Comment: you are right to say that I quoted the wrong WolframAlpha. Thanks for the reply. One question, their answer is valid for all z? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$e^{x}=1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+\frac{x^{3}}{3!}...$

$\frac{1-e^{x}}{x}=-1-\frac{x}{2!}-\frac{x^{2}}{3!}...$

$\int_{0}^{z}\frac{1-e^{x}}{x} dx=-z-\frac{z^{2}}{2.2!}-\frac{z^{3}}{3.3!}...$

Comment: How does this help the OP?